# "undeclared identifier" with MSVC++ 17.34 (VS 22) within decltype-based SFINAE expression

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, visual-studio-2022, sfinae

We are trying to update a C++17 project from VS 19 to VS 22, and all of a sudden, our code does not compile anymore. The problem in question arises in two headers of the [foonathan/memory](https://github.com/foonathan/memory/) libraries, pretty far from our code. The library's own tests compile fine with VS 22. With my limited MSVC++ skill, I was unable to get any information about the actual template instantiation from the error message, which might potentially help.

The errors are all `error C2065: '<some-identifier>': undeclared identifier`, where `<some-identifier>` is the name of a function parameter appearing in a `decltype` expression intended to utilise SFINAE.

One of the 4 locations is [`allocator_storage.hpp:140`](https://github.com/foonathan/memory/blob/main/include/foonathan/memory/allocator_storage.hpp#L140), excerpted here:

```cpp
namespace foonathan::memory {
...
  template <class StoragePolicy, class Mutex>
  class allocator_storage
   : FOONATHAN_EBO(StoragePolicy, ...)
  {
    ...
    template <class OtherPolicy>
    allocator_storage(const allocator_storage<OtherPolicy, Mutex>& other,
      FOONATHAN_SFINAE(new storage_policy(other.get_allocator())))   // <--- HERE, this is line 140
      : storage_policy(other.get_allocator())
    {}
    ...
  };
...
}
```

The full error message I get from MSVC is not helpful, the only extra information is the name of the template being instantiated, without the actual type substitutions:

```
C:\...\foonathan\memory\allocator_storage.hpp(315): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'foonathan::memory::allocator_storage<StoragePolicy,Mutex>' being compiled
C:\...\foonathan\memory\allocator_storage.hpp(140): error C2065: 'other': undeclared identifier
```

With `FOONATHAN_SFINAE(Expr)` being defined as `decltype((Expr), int()) = 0` (no platform configuration whatsoever to be seen anywhere), that error message looks clearly wrong to me - there is an obvious definition of `other` right there.

I'm looking for any hints on what is going on here, or what I could do to help understand the issue. Is there a way to make MSVC print the type it is substituting into the template parameters, like clang and gcc nowadays do? Is there a known issue with MSVC and `decltype`-based SFINAE in method arguments?

Comment: "there is an obvious definition of other right there" IMO something wrong in `FOONATHAN_EBO` (like problem with `class Mutex`), so `allocator_storage` cannot be concretized, so `other` is undefined. I made a simple model for myself, but I cannot fail it in any way: https://godbolt.org/z/eYoWjfWr3

Comment: Have you tried with `/permissive-` (note the minus)? Otherwise, can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Maciej: That is an interesting thought. Interestingly, [another converting constructor](https://github.com/foonathan/memory/blob/df48e667a4fc98a121d1a83f05e975b835d9a7c3/include/foonathan/memory/allocator_storage.hpp#L129) fails in the same way, but does not refer to `allocator_storage` in it's argument list (it does so in a FOONATHAN_REQUIRES within the template parameter list.

Comment: `/permissive-` does not change anything here. I can get rid of the errors if I replace the "undeclared identifier" with a `std::declval`-expression. Still have no clue why it fails, or what actual types are being substituted for the template parameters when it fails.

Comment: @burnpanck Author is still active on Github, you may try to reach him about https://github.com/foonathan/memory/tree/main/include/foonathan/memory

Comment: With the latest msvc version you [get more info](https://godbolt.org/z/b6EvMEPEc), although not really helpful. [C++17 with `\permissive-`](https://godbolt.org/z/3TrcK3Edf) does not compile it either (but [C++17 with `\permissive`](https://godbolt.org/z/E9zWq8cv1) does; note the missing minus). Since clang and gcc do compile it, this is probably a bug. There are various [bug reports](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp?q=decltype+sfinae+C2665&stateGroup=active&ftype=problem) that sound similar, but none that match the problem exactly. What answer do you look for? A workaround?

Comment: @Sedenion: I was looking for anything dependable that allows me to understand the issue, so that we can clearly decide how to proceed. I think with your minimal failing example and the linked bugs, you deserve the bounty - maybe shared with Maciej for the initial MFE even though they missed the /std: flag?

Comment: No problem on my side, bounty is not the most important thing here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal example for the issue is ([live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ErxqqK3bd); thanks to [Maciej Polański](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19165018/maciej-pola%c5%84ski) on whose [original reproduction attempt](https://godbolt.org/z/eYoWjfWr3) this code is based)

```
template <class StoragePolicy>
struct allocator_storage
{
  template <class OtherPolicy>
  allocator_storage(
        allocator_storage<OtherPolicy> const & other,
        decltype(new StoragePolicy(other.storage_policy), int()) = 0)
    : storage_policy(other.storage_policy)
  {
  }

  allocator_storage() = default;

  StoragePolicy storage_policy;
};

int main()
{
  allocator_storage<int> A{};    
  allocator_storage<long> B(A);    
}
```

Both clang and gcc compile it, but MSVC causes an error when using [C++17 with `/permissive-`](https://godbolt.org/z/sWb83KeY5) (but not in [C++17 with `/permissive`](https://godbolt.org/z/x3f9PqMPz), which in C++17 is equal to not specifying anything) and also with [C++20 (regardless of the permissive flag)](https://godbolt.org/z/ErxqqK3bd). As a side note, `/std:c++20` enables `/permissive-` [by default](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/#c-language-modes-and-compatibility-guarantees).

The latest MSVC version (after 19.33) provides a bit more information, namely

```
<source>(22): note: Failed to specialize function template 'allocator_storage<long>::allocator_storage(const allocator_storage<OtherPolicy> &,unknown-type)'
<source>(22): note: With the following template arguments:
<source>(22): note: 'OtherPolicy=int'
<source>(22): note: while trying to match the argument list '(allocator_storage<int>)'
```

while versions <=19.33 do not show this error message. Unfortunately, it doesn't really provide more information.

There are some [bug reports on developer-community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp?q=decltype+sfinae+C2665&stateGroup=active&ftype=problem) (for example [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Overload-resolution-fails-on-a-SFINAE-co/1470172?q=decltype+sfinae+C2665&stateGroup=active&ftype=problem) or [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Alias-type-trait-with-non-type-template/1574139?q=decltype+sfinae+C2665&stateGroup=active&ftype=problem)) that look related, i.e. use SFINAE with `decltype`.

Considering all that (clang and gcc compile the code; existing bug reports), I'd say this is pretty surely a bug in MSVC.

A possible workaround was already mentioned, by replacing the reference to the parameter `other` in the `decltype` with `std::declval` ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/aE5vEYbvx)):

```
decltype(
  new StoragePolicy(std::declval<allocator_storage<OtherPolicy>>().storage_policy), 
  int()) = 0
```

I have noticed that you already reported this [on github](https://github.com/foonathan/memory/issues/145#issue-1460644873).